# Adding ggsignif to plot with numeric x axis results in the error "Can only handle data with groups that are plotted on the x-axis"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a significance layer to a plot using the [ggsignif package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/vignettes/intro.html). However, when trying to add this layer to a plot with a numeric x-axis, I get the message:

> Error in f(...) :
> Can only handle data with groups that are plotted on the x-axis

Here is a reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)

dat <- 
  structure(list(
    SOA = c(50, 150, 300, 900),
    y = c(119, 121, 132, 209)), 
  row.names = c(NA,-4L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

dat %>% 
ggplot(aes(SOA, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_signif(
    annotations = "*",
    y_position = 150,
    xmin = 50,
    xmax = 300)
```

When I plot exactly the same data but transform the x-axis to factor, the significance layer is added successfully. Like so:

```
dat %>% 
ggplot(aes(as.factor(SOA), y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_signif(
    annotations = "*",
    y_position = 150,
    xmin = "50",
    xmax = "300")
```

[image]

Note that this is not what I want, since the distances between the points do not reflect the real distance between them.

**How can I make ggsignif work with a numeric x-axis?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While fixing an unrelated problem, I found out that adding `group = 1` to `aes()` seems to fix the problem:

```
dat %>% 
ggplot(aes(SOA, y, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_signif(
    annotations = "*",
    y_position = 150,
    xmin = 50,
    xmax = 300,
  )
```

[image]

I do not know why it works, but it does.

Comment: I plan on accepting this answer in a couple of days to give the opportunity for someone to add a more complete answer as to why this works.